# Why can I delete but not truncate?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

so I had a bunch of test rows in a table:

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+
| id | name   | guru_id | parent_id | approved | created_ts          | last_edit_ts |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | PHP    |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:27:05 | NULL         |
|  2 | HTML   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:33:21 | NULL         |
|  3 | CSS    |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:34:54 | NULL         |
|  4 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:37:11 | NULL         |
|  5 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:38:39 | NULL         |
|  6 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:40:39 | NULL         |
|  7 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:43:29 | NULL         |
|  8 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:43:59 | NULL         |
|  9 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:45:12 | NULL         |
| 10 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:45:19 | NULL         |
| 11 | test   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:45:39 | NULL         |
| 12 | CSS    |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:46:30 | NULL         |
| 13 | trey   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:48:47 | NULL         |
| 14 | trey   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:49:36 | NULL         |
| 15 | trey   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:50:52 | NULL         |
| 16 | ajax   |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:51:23 | NULL         |
| 17 | jquery |       1 |      NULL |        0 | 2018-07-12 14:51:44 | NULL         |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------+--------------+
```

I eventually got my code working how I wanted, so I tried to `TRUNCATE` the table to start with fresh data using:

`mysql> truncate category`

which returns this error:

> ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`db`.`page`, CONSTRAINT `FK_140AB62012469DE2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `db`.`category` (`id`))

I thought as a joke to get round it try this:

`> delete from category where id != 0;`

and to my surprise, the command worked. Now I have an empty table as desired, but not sure why `delete from` surpasses the foreign key check but not `truncate`? Is there any logic/reason behind this?

Comment: A delete command will take account of the cascade deletion (if it is on). Truncate would only act on the table and not linked records.

Comment: Does this table contain the foreign key or is a value in this table a foreign key to another table? It sounds like the latter in which case I would expect the `DELETE` to work but the truncate to fail...

Comment: @Dragonthoughts oh I see, so truncate just tries to brute force clear whereas delete does the whole cascade thing?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts ah I see, if you wanna add an answer feel free and I can mark as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't really thought of it as big enough to be an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `delete` command will take account of the cascade deletion (if it is on) or fail if it isn't.

`Truncate` would only act on the table and not linked records. `Truncate` essentially tries to drop all the data pages and indices for the table without regard to other tables - foreign key constraints prevent this.

Truncate is effectively `drop table` followed by create table of same schema.